# Bootstrap 3.0 and Font Awesome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I have been using Bootstrap and Font Awesome for a while now with no problems. It seems that when I changed over to Bootstrap 3 the Font Awesome icons are no longer showing up in IE10 and Firefox. But it works fine in Chrome and Safari.

I have the same icons in a project I did in RC1/RC2 and that still works fine. Anyone know what happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See also: [Updating Bootstrap to version 3 - what do I have to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974998/updating-bootstrap-to-version-3-what-do-i-have-to-do/) in RC1 the Glyphicons had been removed. Glyphicons are back since RC2 (180 glyphs in font format from the Glyphicon Halflings set).
Maybe this cause your troubles. Try to remove the Glyphicons from the bootstrap CSS. Remove the line `@import "glyphicons.less";` from your bootstrap.less and rebuild Bootstrap.

Also check Glyphicon and font-awesome need different font formats for different browsers (.eot,.woff,.ttf,.svg). If one is broken or missing it will not work on some browsers.

Comment: He's talking about Font Awesome, not the glyphicons.

Comment: @flavien yes, i know. That's why i said: "Try to remove the Glyphicons from the bootstrap CSS". Maybe there is a conflict between Glyphicons (bundled by default) and font-awesome. But cause the different result on different browsers some font are missing most likely.

Answer (score 0):

For Font Awesome CSS version 4.7.0: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

FontAwesome is the iconic font designed for use with Twitter Bootstrap:

You may find this helpful too: http://www.jsdelivr.com/projects/fontawesome