# Glyphicons from bootstrap 3 not rendering on Firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap 3 for a web application. 
Everything works on my computer (Chrome, IE and Firefox) but one of my customer can not see glyphicon.

I first thought the problem was my css but the client does not see either glyphicons on getboostrap.com [image]
The problem is only present in Firefox. On Chrome and IE it works.

I checked the Network tab of Firebug and I could not find a single font file download ...

Does anyone have an idea to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check all your fonts are present and upload well in your font dir, see also: [Bootstrap 3.0 and Font Awesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493101/bootstrap-3-0-and-font-awesome/18497171), .eot,.woff,.ttf,.svg. If one is broken or missing it will not work on some browsers:

files:

```
css/bootstrap.css
fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot  
fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg  
fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf  
fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

Comment: I checked links and it works for other persons. What I don t understand is that website getbootstrap.com doesn t work on ffirefox to (seen screenshot)

Comment: check: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-fonts-and-colors-websites-use#w_custom-fonts

Comment: The screen shot indicates that their Firefox settings are over-riding fonts in general. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems

Comment: @BassJobsen Thanks for the link. It's the solution !

Comment: How would we enable them by default without users having to individually adjust their firefox settings?