# How to migrate template from twitter bootstrap v2.0 to twitter bootstrap v3.0

Tags: templates, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, twitter-bootstrap-3, updates

Many days ago I make my template in twitter bootstrap v2.0. Now I want to upgrade it with twitter bootstrap v3.0. How can I migrate my template from twitter bootstrap v2.0 to twitter bootstrap v3.0.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974998/updating-bootstrap-to-version-3-what-do-i-have-to-do . Maybe the question is still asked no ?

Answer (score 1):

**From the Bootply Docs**

[**Migration from Bootstrap 2.x**](http://bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide#migration)

And this **[Migration Tool](http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/)** could be useful