# Twitter Bootstrap support for IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have my application built upon latest `Bootstrap Version 3.0.3`. Everything was running fine on `Chrome and Mozilla`. Now suddenly, people want it to support `IE7 and IE8`. I have tried implementing [Bootstrap 3 for IE7](https://github.com/coliff/bootstrap-ie7) , but it didn't help. Everything still stays dis-aligned.

Things are still messed up in IE 7 and IE8.

Do I need to manually override the Bootstrap Styles? I doubt, bootstrap being so extensible and popular, must have done something to support IE7.

Comment: They explicitly do not support ie7. There is that workaround but you must make sure the .htc file is the root path from the html source, not the css, so check the path of the .htc file. It does work making columns work and other things, but the javascript files are not necessarily going to work in IE7.

Comment: And you have to use respond.js for non-responsive browsers. See the Docs on GetBootstrap.com

Comment: http://theie7countdown.com/ - less than 1% world wide.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't use Twitter's Bootstrap 3 if you will have to support IE7. Twitter's Bootstrap 3 has many changes ([Updating Bootstrap to version 3 - what do I have to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974998/updating-bootstrap-to-version-3-what-do-i-have-to-do/18069643#18069643), http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/its-a-shame-the-newest-version-of-githubs-most-popular-projects-is-not-backward-compatible/) don't try to fix them for IE7. Consider to use the latest 2.3.2 version, nothing wrong with it. You simple can't have both; support for older browsers and the newest HTML / CSS support.

Comment: I'll get the version of 2.3.2 of bootstrap. I'll be grateful if it works :)

Comment: Worked, but I lost the panel css and few more... Which would be easier to incorporate... Thanks Buddy!

Comment: @BassJobsen :: Should you migrate your website from Twitter’s Bootstrap 2.x to 3? Amen to your blog post.

Comment: Works :) If only I found this post sooner it would have saved me a headache.