# Bootstrap 3 is not supporting the IE 8 and IE 7

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have developed an application using Asp.Net Mvc 4 and bootstrap 3 for UI, everything is running fine on Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox but the bootstrap 3 is not supporting the IE 7 & IE 8.

What to do with the bootstrap 3 to make it support the IE 7 & IE 8?

Comment: Can you describe what parts that are not working in IE, as I'm pretty sure the whole site does'nt break down. Perhaps related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947182/ie8-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-3

Comment: You can try using [modernizer](http://modernizr.com/docs/)

Comment: There are notes on the bootstrap site about this, noting what JS libraries are needed to support IE8.  IE7 is explicitly not supported - if you really need this, you may want to consider bootstrap 2, or looking into one of the patches that can be found.

Comment: No one has IE7! Don't bother trying to make your Websites sopport it, its not worth the time! http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201307-201407

Answer (score 5):

Bootstrap 3 officially dropped support for IE7, but you can try a polyfill library such as: https://github.com/coliff/bootstrap-ie7 if you really need support for such an old browser (such as in a corporate environment).

IE8 is currently supported (but will be dropped in Bootstrap v4).  In order to get IE8 to work properly, you will need to add respond.js to your app.

```
<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2):

Officially IE7 is not supported. IE8 and IE9 will be support.

[check bootstrap doc](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support)

check this [link](http://www.joostrap.com/blog/bootstrap-3-supporting-internet-explorer-8-and-9) to make it support in Internet Explorer 8 and 9.

---

Making Twitter Bootstrap 3 Compatible with Internet Explorer 7 and below

[check this link](http://www.extremecss.com/making-twitter-bootstrap-3-compatible-with-internet-explorer-7-and-below/)

---

Don't use Twitter's Bootstrap 3 if you will have to support IE7. Twitter's Bootstrap 3 has many changes ([Updating Bootstrap to version 3 - what do I have to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974998/updating-bootstrap-to-version-3-what-do-i-have-to-do/18069643#18069643), http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/its-a-shame-the-newest-version-of-githubs-most-popular-projects-is-not-backward-compatible/) don't try to fix them for IE7. Consider to use the latest 2.3.2 version, nothing wrong with it. You simple can't have both; support for older browsers and the newest HTML / CSS support.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20615535/twitter-bootstrap-support-for-ie7)

Answer (score 0):

If you just dont want to spend too much time on old technology like IE8 and below,

please give a look at https://github.com/hereblur/onesize-css

It's simply remove responsive from IE8 and convert the web size to desktop version on IE8 and below without touching responsive support on other browser.

Tested and works on IE8 (soon for IE7 and below). may be you can give it a try.