# Issue with bootstrap 3.3.4 forms in IE7

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, internet-explorer-7, respond.js

I'm currently trying to fix an app using bootstrap to work in IE7. It is causing me a serious headache.

So far most elements look good now that I have done the following:

Included respond.js
Included html5shiv.js

But I am having problems with the following markup:

```
<div class="form-group ng-scope">
    <div class="form-group ">
       <label class="col-sm-2 control-label ng-binding" for="">Forename</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
           <div>
               <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" id="" ng-model="field.value.text">
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In all browsers except IE7 the label appears to the left inline with the text element. But in IE7 it appears above.

Are there any known issues here? I've noticed some of the elements are using display:table; and I'm aware this isn't supported in IE7.

Comment: Downgraded from version 3.3.4 to 2.3.2 as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20615535/twitter-bootstrap-support-for-ie7)

Comment: still on IE7? please grow up... :P kidding. only 0.03% usage! http://caniuse.com/usage-table

Comment: @Ravimallya haha if it was my choice we wouldn't be supporting it!

Comment: Target IE7 and 'force it' into place.

Comment: @TomMiller If you would need to the the website compatible with IE7, then go for [bootstrap 2.3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) or [cascade framework](http://www.cascade-framework.com/index.html). I've not used/checked the second one. If your issue resolved, either answer your own question or delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgraded from version 3.3.4 to 2.3.2