# Does AngularUI/Bootstrap support twitter-bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

Dropdown menu not working in Angular-UI-Bootstrap? Using Bootstrap-3 CSS

The following is the code. The link `Click me for a dropdown` shows up. But does not toggle on click.  What is wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script>function DropdownCtrl($scope) {
 $scope.items = [
  "The first choice!",
  "And another choice for you.",
  "but wait! A third!"
 ];
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.5.0.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/dropdownToggle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>                  
<li ng-controller="DropdownCtrl" class="dropdown">
   <a href='#' class="dropdown-toggle"> Click me for a dropdown </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li ng-repeat="choice in items"><a>{{choice}}</a>
          </li> 
        </ul>
</li>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Angular-UI/Bootstrap does not support Bootstrap 3 (yet).

You can track issues on [331](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/331) and  [742](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/742)

Comment: Are there any workarounds to provide toggling that you have found?

Comment: I'm not using angular ui. toggling works fine in both bootstrap 2.3.2 and bootstrap 3

Answer (score 11):

As of [about 10/1/13](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/794), yes it does!

It appears even the pesky [Accordion & Collapse issues](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/1208) have been resolved as well.

Comment: Has the formatting of the the Datepicker been fixed as well ?

Comment: Just dropped the cdn (<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" rel="stylesheet">) into this PLUNKR http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview. Doesn't seem to be there yet..

Comment: As of today it does not work. I ended up using bootstrap-datepicker mixed with angular-strap, but it is kind of painful since it doesn't map automatically the dates, you have to manually assign in your controller.