# Bootstrap 3 modal in html5mode in Angularjs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Using Bootstrap Modal in `html5Mode(true)`.

On clicking `launch demo modal` upon 1st click the url changes to `/#myModal` modal does not appear.

Upon clicking again `launch demo modal` the modal appears.

In normal mode (`$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);` the modal appears on the first click.

How do i make the Modal appear in the first click?

standard modal code:-

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Launch demo modal</a>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>

      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Angular code :-

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/home',
        controller: 'homePage'
      }).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Upon inspection the page refreshes on the first click of `launch demo modal` but the refresh does not take place thru server. Angular manages that. Similarly upon the second click too, angular manages the REST request, and shows the modal.

PS:- I wanted to demonstrate the problem but [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wThAzbCTIapW6Tu6PzDx) does not work in html5Mode.

And I couldn't add additional html page to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sangramfuture/WB77N/) so far as i can tell, you can't. Besides i'm not sure if it supports `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` mode.

Where do i go to demonstrate errors ?

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at Angular-UI for Bootstrap directives (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal). There is one for modals.

Comment: last time i checked there were serious issues with it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205329/does-angularui-bootstrap-support-twitter-bootstrap-3/18215522#18215522

Comment: They released a new version since you had a look at it. They reworked the $modal provider (also eliminating $dialog). I made a working Plunker to show you how you can use AngularJS 1.0.8, AngularUI 0.6.0 and Bootstrap 3.0 together.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/WLJfs8axxMJ419N2osBY?p=preview

It is not using the data-toggle attribute as in the Bootstrap example, but instead an `ng-click` directive to trigger a function in the controller which instantiate the modal.

I used the modal example directly from Bootstrap ([Bootstrap Modal Live Demo](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)), and adapted it for the javascript example from AngularUI ([AngularUI Modal Demo](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)).

**Versions used**

- AngularJS 1.0.8
- AngularUI 0.6.0
- Bootstrap  3.0.0

**Result**

[image]

**index.html** (partial)

```
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
    <div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>
</div>
```

**modal.html**

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="cancel()">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">
          <a ng-click="selected.item=item">{{item}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div>Selected Item: {{selected.item}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.open = function () {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'modal.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
};

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```

Also, there is a small css fix for the modal visibility.

```
.modal {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't fade when it is closing. In prev version, I used to add some properties to give it fade efect on closing, such as `backDropFade: true`, however I cannot find in this version. And it disappears suddenly and it is not cool.

Comment: You should know that AngularUI does not fully support Bootstrap 3.0

Comment: so does it mean, it closed just this way? couldnt I add effect on closing?

Comment: Sure you can, but you would have to do it yourself or wait until a new version of AngularUI and hope it is supported.