# bootstrap modal just shows darkened screen (no modal)

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have http://chessresearcher.com/test-02.html which should load http://chessresearcher.com/hello.html as a modal, but it doesn't display it! What am I doing wrong? I have kept the code to bare minimum. The code source is http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=modal-with-remote-url which works.

http://chessresearcher.com/test-02.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Example of Twitter Bootstrap Modals with Remote URL</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('#button_id').click(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show')
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="bs-example">
    <!-- Button HTML (to Trigger Modal) -->
    <a href="hello.html" role="button" id="button_id" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch Demo Modal</a>

    <!-- Modal HTML -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3>Confirmation</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <!-- Content will be loaded here from a remote source  -->
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

and: http://chessresearcher.com/hello.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>untitled</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

</head>

<body>

<p>Hello, World!</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the combination of angular ui and bootstrap 3.  I can't find the link that solved the problem for me, but the solution was to add this css:

```
.modal {
display: block;
height: 0;
overflow: visible;
}
```

See also [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205329/does-angularui-bootstrap-support-twitter-bootstrap-3?lq=1).